# How can I control telecom status of android cell phone by react-native?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to know to **telecom status** values when **receive call**
because I want change telecom status when normal as receive call

How can i get values and control status

> - nomal : 0
> - receive call : 1
> - calling : 2
> - power off : 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-detection`

Trust this helps.

Comment: Perhaps I found something like this Thx!